# How to avoid strange edges when adding cells to a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

When a user taps a cell in a `UITableViewController` Grouped-View, I want a few cells to drop down below the first cell. I `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and I change the number of rows in the cell, but when the cells drop down (using the `UITableViewRowAnimationTop`animation, there is some "artifact" occurring on the top right and left corners of the original cell.

I believe this is because the cell that is coming down has square corners, but the cell that's originally there has rounded corners. So, when the cell first appears, you can see the square corners behind the original cell.

Has anyone had this problem and know a solution to it? I can post a video if needed for clarity.

Comment: Try `UITableViewRowAnimationFade`. This scenario looks almost exactly the same using fade, except there are no artifacts. Otherwise, if you can use a solid background color, you can use a custom cell to force the background to be opaque and cover up the artifacts (note, this can work with the default pinstripe background because the edges rounded corners of the cell only touch one color). The only other solution I can think of is to modify the animation in-flight using `CADisplayLink`. If you want to explore one of these other solutions, let me know and I'll try and mock something up.